# Get data from mongodb with dynamic nested levels using nodejs and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

For example
I have one table:

`Menuid, menuname, parentid, levelid` -- this is table

Consider the values:

```
Menuid:Pg, menuname:mainprogram, programid:'', levelid: 1
Menuid:sb, menuname:subprogram, programid:'Pg', levelid: 2
Menuid:cb, menuname:childprogram, programid:'sb', levelid: 3
Menuid:Pg2, menuname:mainprogram2, programid:'', levelid: 1
```

Output:

```
[ {
  Menuid:'Pg',
  Menuname:'mainprogram',
  Children:[ {
    Menuid:'sb',
    Menuname:'subprogram',
    Children:[ {
      Menuid:'cb',
      Menuname:'childprogram'
    } ]
  } ]
}, {
  Menuid:'Pg2',
  Menuname:'mainprogram2'
} ]
```

getting menu code

```
exports.getMenus = (req, res, next) => {
// need clarification
}
```

model for menu

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');
const menuSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    menuId: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    menuName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    icon: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    type: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    url: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    levelId: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    programId: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    order: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    createdBy: {
        type: String,
        require: false
    },
    createdDate: {
        type: Date,
        require: false,
    },
    updatedBy: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        require: false
    },
    updatedDate: {
        type: Date,
        default: '',
        require: false,
    },
});
menuSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Menu', menuSchema);
```

router:

```
router.get('/getmenus/:id', MenuController.getMenus);
```

user request from client like
http://localhost:3000/api/menu/getmenus/pg
getmenus after slash word is a required menus under submenus

Note: if each data has order menans based on menu object need to render with that order. Please provide any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer below link
your expected behaviour will be available in this graphlookup 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/